# HttpURLConnection TIMEOUT for non-standard HTTP ports

Tags: android, http, jersey, httpurlconnection

I developed a jersey rest service for my android app and want to use a custom port other than 80 to access the service. But when I try to connect to the server via the custom port (51001), I always get a SocketException indicating that the connection timed out. On the server side, there are no incomming connections from the android device. But when I switch the port of the server to 80, everything works fine. Does anybody have a idea why?

Here's my sample code from the android application:

```
protected HttpResponse download(String urlString) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_MS);
    connection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_MS);
    return HttpResponse.fromURLConnection(connection);
}
```

PS: There's no firewall etc. blocking the port and the previous version of the app is working (without the URLConnection API). So the issue is on the URLConnection API.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT //

Here's the exception, which is thrown (with timeout of 40 seconds):

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /IP (port 51001) after 40000ms

It does not depend on the timeout, increasing of the timeout has no effect. Moreover, when I use port 80 everything works fine with the same timeout.

Comment: how much is `TIMEOUT_MS`? and can you post the exception stack too?

Comment: Please take a look at my edited question. It does not depend on the ammount of the timeout ;-(

Comment: When I try to access the jersey resource with the browser, everything works fine, too (with port 51001).

Comment: can you try your **URL** with something like this `URL url = new URL("http", "your_domain.com", 51001, "/rest_api/bla_bla");`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I already tried it, but with the same results ;-(

Comment: `try to access the jersey resource with the browser,`. With a browser on your android device?

Comment: Hi, I tried it with the browser on the android phone with no luck. But on the pc it works. So, I guess it's a problem with the firewall ;-( But with the old App and a plain Socket-Conenction on the same port,it works...

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue with an app installed on an Asus Zenfone running Android 5. The app works fine on every other device, and is able to connect to my REST service (a python app on port 5000 of a cloud server). The Asus's HTTP requests are never received by that server, whether through my app or via web browser. It can, however, connect to other apps running on that same webserver, so long as they are port 80. Have you any followup to your issue?